# Do I need to factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset

I have downloaded a bunch of apps on my 3-year-old Lenovo Android tablet. Lately, several of the app icons have been turned into little green android images. Also, the books I've downloaded to Acrobat Reader are inaccessible. Do I need a factory reset? If I do, how can I get back the great books that I was looking forward to reading?

Comment: Did you remove your micro Sd card from the device?